# Android remote server application design

Tags: android, remote-server

I'm new to android development. I want to make a specific application: We have a take out restaurant. The restaurant takes orders from android devices (they send requests probably to a remote server) someone at the restaurant has to see the order at real time to proccess it.

**My question is this:** What is the prefered android way (if there is such) of of designing such a system. For example, I've heard that a good way to do this is to query a php server through http with JSON info. What other ways would you recommend and why?